# QCQP as a SDP or SOCP?

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, semidefinite-programming, qcqp, second-order-cone-programming

I have a QCQP as shown below: 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned} & \underset{\mathbf{x}}{\text{minimize}} &  & \mathbf{x}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{P}\cdot\mathbf{x}\\
 & \text{subject to} &  & \mathbf{x}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{P}_{i}\cdot\mathbf{x}-r_{eq}^{i}=0, &  & i\in S_{eq}\\
 &  &  & \mathbf{x}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{P}_{j}\cdot\mathbf{x}-r_{max}^{j}<0, &  & j\in S_{iq}\\
 &  &  & \mathbf{x}>\mathbf{x}_{min}\\
 &  &  & \mathbf{x}<\mathbf{x}_{max}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

$\mathbf{P}$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite. $\mathbf{P}_i$ and $\mathbf{P}_j$ are symmetric but not PSD as they have the following particular shape:

$
\mathbf{P}_{i}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
p_{i1} & \dots & p_{in}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \dots & 0
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
p_{i1} & \dots & p_{in}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \dots & 0
\end{bmatrix}^{T}
$

My approach is to relax the constraints using a Taylor approximation and convert the problem to a convex one. This provides decent results, depending, obviously, on the point that I use for the Taylor approximation.

Recently I stumbled over https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/relaxations.pdf and I tried to set the problem as a SDP as below:

\begin{aligned} & \underset{\mathbf{x,X}}{\text{minimize}} &  & \mathbf{Tr(XP)}\\
 & \text{subject to} &  & \mathbf{Tr(X}\mathbf{P}_{i})-r_{eq}^{i}=0, &  & i\in S_{eq}\\
 &  &  & \mathbf{Tr(X}\mathbf{P}_{j})-r_{max}^{j}<0, &  & j\in S_{iq}\\
 &  &  & \left[\begin{array}{cc}
\mathbf{X} & \mathbf{x}\\
\mathbf{x^{T}} & 1
\end{array}\right]\mathbf{\succeq0}\\
 &  &  & \mathbf{x}>\mathbf{x}_{min}\\
 &  &  & \mathbf{x}<\mathbf{x}_{max}
\end{aligned}

However, from what I understand, the SDP formulation only provides a lower bound on the objective function. Then, in order to get an actual feasible point, one has to run an iterative process in which the problem is linearised and solved again and again. However, in my case,  due to the equality constraints obtaining random feasible points is not that easy.

While digging on the subject I also found out about SOCP. However, I was not able to find any resources that show how to convert a non-convex QCQP to a SOCP. I found some examples for the cases where all the $\mathbf{P}$ matrices are PSD, but none that address problems similar to mine.

So my questions are as follows:

1. Can a nonconvex QCQP problem as the one described above be set in a SOCP form?
2. If yes, does the SOCP solver provides (as in the case of SDP) just a lower bound on the objective function or also a feasible point for the original problem?
3. Are there some good techniques for obtaining feasible starting points for the iterative process mentioned above (the one that runs after solving the SDP)?
4. Any other ideas on how could I approach the original problem?

Comment: A Google search for "nonconvex qcqp" offers a wealth of resources. I dare say that anyone here is just going to summarize what they find there. Let me suggest, then, that you do that literature search yourself, and consider submitting your findings as an answer to this question. I'm ready to give some karma! :-)

Comment: Hi Michael! You can imagine that someone who is rather new to optimization had to go down the "google" path a few times in order to get to the point where they are able to formulate a question here. My problem is not that I'm not able to search google, but I fail to understand the practical usefulness of SDP or SOCP for QCQP. If all they do is to provide a theoretical lower bound on the objective function, and to get a feasible point you have to anyway solved a linearised version, then what is the point?

Comment: Take this example: http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/seq_matlab/ncqp.m. The lower bound obtained from via Lagrange dual is far away from the values obtained from the iterative process mentioned above.

Comment: I understand what you're saying---but I'm suggesting that nonconvex QCQP is just not something a lot of people have decent practical experience with. The people that have such knowledge and experience are more likely to be found through the search than here on Math.SE, particularly for a question as general and broad as the one you've offered. For specific pieces---for instance, the utility of the SDP Lagrange bound---there might be some help available here.

Comment: I would try first to see if a general purpose global solver like Baron or Couenne is doing good enough. There is also GloMiQO (or its more general brother Antigone).